# CodeIgniter Error Reporting Level

Tags: php, codeigniter

As far as I'm aware, setting the error reporting to

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));
```

or

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Should suppress all errors including notices.

However it doesn't do that for me.

I'm not asking for a lecture on how if there is a warning or a notice, it should be fixed instead of covered up. The notice I am trying to suppress is from a third party library and I'm not about to go in and start changing it.

Why do neither of those error reporting settings actually suppress the PHP Notices?

**Edit:**

I'm aware of the environment settings and I am using the correct environment string.

**Edit 2:**

I've checked the settings in my PHP Configuration and the errors aren't set to show. Are the notices generated by CodeIgniter itself? I say this because in a standalone application outside of CodeIgniter no warning is displayed for an undefined index, whereas in CodeIgniter it is.

**Edit 3:**

I've put in the fix from the topic suggested in the comments below (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066376/how-to-disable-showing-php-errors-in-codeigniter-2-1-3). I've also put the following in my .htaccess

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag log_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag report_memleaks off
php_flag track_errors off
php_value error_reporting 0
php_value log_errors_max_len 0
```

Still to no avail...

Comment: Please see index.php file in root folder you will find more information inside the file. (`APPLICATION ENVIROMENT`)

Comment: Where do you think I am referring too? I'm working in the index.php file but like I said, it's not doing what I understand it should.

Comment: You could refer to anywhere in your site, it is not mentioned in your Q in what file you are making edits... Please see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15066376/1564365) as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066376/how-to-disable-showing-php-errors-in-codeigniter-2-1-3

Answer (score 0):

On line **45** (in a fresh installation) in **index.php**:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

Try changing it to:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

Comment: That line doesn't exist in my index.php however I already have `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');` set

Comment: Then I believe that your server configuration sets "more" global conditions on `error_reporting()`.

Comment: Try running your application on another server, for example on shared hosting (not localhost). :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed - was a third party library overwriting it.

See my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20948353/1209020